# Make a slider with an array in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, slider

my question goes as follows;

I want to create an interface in which you can change a parameter through a Slider and  make  the changes  on the plot appear accoordingly. The problem  is  that , using the Slider() function in matplotlib  , I can't  choose the  exact parameters  I  want to be in the slide bar. ( Just the beginning , the end and the step size). Is there a way that I could give an array with the values I want ? Thanks.  Here is the example from 
matplotlib webpage:

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
  t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
  a0 = 5
  f0 = 3
  s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)
  l, = plt.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
  plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

  axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
  axfreq = plt.axes([0.03, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65])
  axamp = plt.axes([0.08, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65])
  sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0,valinit=f0,valstep=delta_f)
  samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)


  def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

  sfreq.on_changed(update)
  samp.on_changed(update)

  resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
  button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

  def reset(event):

   sfreq.reset()
   samp.reset()

  button.on_clicked(reset)

  rax = plt.axes([0.5, 0.025, 0.15, 0.15])
  radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
  def colorfunc(label):
  l.set_color(label)
  fig.canvas.draw_idle()
  radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

  plt.show()
```

Arguments for the Class Slide:

class matplotlib.widgets.Slider(ax, label, valmin, valmax, valinit=0.5, valfmt='%1.2f', closedmin=True, closedmax=True, slidermin=None, slidermax=None, dragging=True, valstep=None, **kwargs)

As you can see,in both sliders, just the initial value, final value and step size are given ( in sfreq and samp).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check your indentation, this code doesn't run as-is

Comment: Can you use this example to explain what you want to achieve? Like what parameters would you like to pass to achieve which exact effect?